# AWS ElasticSearch configure in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.4, elasticsearch, aws

Is anyone tried using AWS ElasticSearch in Magento 2.3.4.

When i tried to configure it in Magento, connection failed.

AWS ElasticSearch give the https endpoint, does Magento support HTTPS for elastic search?

Also, anyone tried ElasticSuite?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I configured it today. After some investigation the following settings worked for me:

- In Magento Admin configure the AWS endpoint url in "Elasticsearch Server Hostname" field.
- I used port 443
- Enable HTTP auth
- Enter your username and pwd. I use the "Master user" setting in AWS elasticsearch and filled in these credentials in Magento

Make sure you reindex (but I think you know that)